# emacs: Terminal type xterm-256color is not defined

Tags: linux, emacs, fedora

When I use my alias:

```
ne = emacs -nw
```

I get:

```
Terminal type xterm-256color is not defined.
```

I am using a Fedora dump.

Also, when I'm typing in my terminal, the backspace key actually adds a space instead of removing it.

This randomly happened when I was messing with `ncurses` in Atom.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by adding TERM=xterm in the .bashrc instead of the standard xterm-256color, works perfectly as before.

Comment: Do you still get syntax highlighting?